Can I use a 120VDC Power Supply to power a device that needs a 120VAC power supply?
Can this ->
https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0B771K1YL/ref=ewc_pr_img_1?smid=A1JTMEV1RY2RCR&th=1
Power this? ->
https://assets.omega.com/pdf/process-heaters-and-coolers/duct-heaters/AHP_SERIES.pdf
At the very least just for testing purposes. I believe the output wattage will be the same or at least very similar for 120VDC, 0.3A. (36 Watts) for 120VAC, 0.3A. (36 Watts).
Or am I mistaken?

Are you trying to run the heater at a lower wattage than it is designed for?

No, I am intended to just use it in the lower wattage ranges.

Yes, it will work. The heater is just a resistor. It will work just fine on DC vs. AC.
120 VAC(rms), which is how line voltage is normally measured/specified, gives the same amount of heat as 120 VDC.

It will be fine for test purposes, same wattage.
It's conceivable that reliability may be negatively affected as it is for light bulbs run on DC (perhaps via a different mechanism, eg. the presence of moisture causing electrolytic corrosion rather than notching), but at the low wattages you mention I suspect not much.
